# TikzPicture: xshift,yshift

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Let A,B be nodes in a tikzpicture ambient. There is an equivalent of:

```
      right = of A
      left  = of A
      above = of A
      below = of A
```

in order to do nothing and using only xshift,yshit to describe the position of B respect to A?

for instance

```
     \node[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,  ????? = of A] (B) {B};
```

Comment: You can write shifts relative to A with calc library `\node[shift={($(A.center) +(1,1)$)}] (B) {B};`. But I don't understand your problem.

Comment: `at (A)` outside the options will do it.  I prefer to use `at (A)` even when I use`[right]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid using `above right of`, you can use

```
\node[xshift=1cm, yshift=1cm, at=(A)] (B) {B};
```

Note that you can also specify distance using `above right of`:

```
\node[above right=1cm and 1cm of A] (B) {B};
```